# LINQ order a collection of objects by date in descending order

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a bunch of objects(products) and I want to order them by date created in descending order first and then only display the top 10 records.
The format of the date created(DateTime) is as as follow.

```
4/4/2007 12:00:00 AM
```

This is what I have tried.

How can I sort the top 10 in descending order by date?

```
var productLatestReleases = (from p in visualsProduct
                                 from pf in p.DomainObjectFields
                                 select p).Distinct().OrderByDescending(d => d.DateCreated).Take(10);
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing...?

Comment: That query appears to be correct what results are you getting

Comment: Why do you query `p.DomainObjectFields` at all? You don't need it. The whole thing can be shortened to `visualsProduct.Distinct().OrderByDescending(p=>p.DateCreated).Take(10)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are describing the format of the date, I suppose that the datatype of the `DateCreated` property is `string`. If it is then you could do:

```
.OrderByDescending(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d.DateCreated)).Take(10)
```

Also, your `Distinct()` will not have much effect if you don't specify your own equality to compare.

Comment: You **can't** specify custom equality comparer using LINQ to Entities, because `Distinct(comparer)` is not supported ...

Comment: [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

Comment: Ok, i see your point. I guess that it is implicit that Linq to Entities is used by looking at the Tag. Sorry about that.