# Ordering a list based on date-time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am importing a set of date-time values from the server. The order is a mixed bag:

```
2020-02-16 00:24:23
2020-02-14 12:50:21
2020-02-15 21:32:12
2020-02-13 05:32:06
```

I would like these values to be added to a list/array and order them based on date-time. What would be a better solution to go for? Array or List? And how do I order them?

```
public List<string> DateTime;

void Start()
{
  DateTime.Add(time_val);
}
```

Comment: Dont store them as string? Or store in y m d h m s order

Comment: @BugFinder okay and how do I store them as? Since the raw input I am getting is in DateTime format.

Comment: welcome new user, here's the exact answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16105117/294884

Comment: Keep them as date time format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First collect all lines to single string or list of your choice use [StreamReader.ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time).

```
// Read the file and display it line by line.  
System.IO.StreamReader file =
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");  
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
{  
    System.Console.WriteLine(line);  
    counter++;  
}
```

For ordering, you can use [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) for ordering anything including Datetime variable. [Sort date time list by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070517/sort-datetime-list-by-time/18070556) is similar question.

```
var list = dateList.OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay).ToList();
```

Comment: StreamReader is irrelevant here

Comment: @Fattie I think OP didn't mention, how he receives or in which format. So I just assumed. But there are many ways to read string, so answer is still on the post for ordering DateTime.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
           string input = "2020-02-16 00:24\n" +
                           "2020-02-14 12:50\n" +
                           "2020-02-15 21:32\n" +
                           "2020-02-13 05:32";

            List<DateTime> dates = input.Split(new char[] { '\n' }).Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I am not giving the input string in my code, I will be receiving the raw input as I showed in the question so I cannot add "\n" to the input.

Comment: Your input has an invisible carriage return since each date is on its own line.